# Eclipse E4 does not start with Java web start

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, java-web-start, e4

I export my Eclipse E4 applcation to java web start jars + jnlp files.
When I start my application I got some info message and one error.

```
    !SESSION Tue Oct 11 15:00:05 CEST 2016 -----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-10-11 15:00:05.475
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "loadLibrary.C:\Users\air27654\.eclipse\1480097773_win32_win32_x86_64\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher\5624ca9-47d77677\eclipse_1617.dll")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkLink(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.JNIBridge.loadLibrary(JNIBridge.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.JNIBridge.takeDownSplash(JNIBridge.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.takeDownSplash(Main.java:2226)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main$SplashHandler.run(Main.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:247)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain.basicRun(WebStartMain.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain.main(WebStartMain.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have searched the internet and did found that adding this to the jnlp file it should be fixed:

```
<security>
    <all-permissions></all-permissions>
  </security>
```

However the changed didn't fix the problem. Can someone help me with this issue?
My full jnlp file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+"  
    codebase="http://localhost" href="test2.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>CR-IT System Platform</title>
    <vendor>cr</vendor>
    <description>This is my simple JWS Eclipse 
     application test.</description>
  </information>
  <!--request all permissions from the application. This does not change-->
  <security>
    <all-permissions></all-permissions>
  </security>
  <!-- The name of the main class to execute. This does not change-->
  <application-desc main-class="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WebStartMain" />
  <resources>
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar"/>
    <extension name="CR_IT_Client_Feature" 
     href="features/CR_IT_Client_Feature_1.0.0.new.jnlp" />
    <property name="eclipse.product" 
     value="CR-IT_client.product" />
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows">
    <j2se version="1.7+" />
  </resources>
</jnlp>
```